# Cannot run Playwright test --ui if Playwright package is installed

Tags: reactjs, playwright

I'm trying to run `npx playwright test --ui` to run the playwright e2e test files, I believe this keys off of the "@playwright/test" package.

I also have a need for the "playwright" package to leverage the 'chromium' module. The problem is that after I install "playwright", when I try to run the tests, I get the following error:

```
nextjs-ramen % npx playwright test --ui       
 Please install @playwright/test package to use Playwright Test.
 npm install -D @playwright/test
```

After I run the suggested command `npm install -D @playwright/test`, it gives me the same error as mentioned above. I'm new to playwright, so I'm not sure if there is a configuration I need to have both @playwright/test and playwright packages work

Comment: Appears to be an open bug: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/23098

Answer (score 1):

I honestly didn't encounter this issue, but usually, if you uninstall and install Playwright again might rectify the issue. If you are using VS code, I suggest using the Playwright extension to install it. It sorts out so many issues. However, there are some similar problems and answered in following links

https://github.com/Microsoft/playwright/issues/6981

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/23098

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having this issue, but what OS and node/npm version are you on?

the `@playwright/test` package and the `playwright` library shouldn't need to both be installed (see https://playwright.dev/docs/library), and I'm pretty sure it can cause issues if you have both. The general rule of thumb is: if you need the testing framework, use `/test`, and if you jut want browser automation, use the base library. You should be able to use the chromium fixture from /test via `import { chromium } from '@playwright/test';`.